# OpenCl shared virtual memory test strange results

Tags: c, kernel, opencl, shared-memory, gpgpu

I am trying to test the new OpenCl 2.0 SVM features. I am using AMD-APP-SDK on a machine that has the following SVM capabilities:

- CL_DEVICE_SVM_COARSE_GRAIN_BUFFER: 1 (Supported)
- CL_DEVICE_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_BUFFER:   1 (Supported)
- CL_DEVICE_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_SYSTEM:   0 (Not Supported)
- CL_DEVICE_SVM_ATOMICS:             0 (Not Supported)

I am testing with a very simple example in which I do the following (after setting up OpenCL objects of course):

**On the host side:**

- Allocate an SVM buffer.
- Map, Fill, and Unmap that buffer.
- Setup the kernel.
- Pass the SVM buffer as argument.
- Invoke the kernel.

**Here is the relevant host code:**

```
int status;
cl_int cl_status;
int num_elements = 10;

status = SetupKernel("test_svm_kernel.cl", "test_svm_kernel");
CHECK_ERROR(status, "SetupKernel");

svm_input = clSVMAlloc(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, num_elements*sizeof(int),
                      0);
CHECK_ALLOCATION(svm_input, "svm_input");


cl_status = clEnqueueSVMMap(queue, CL_TRUE,
                            CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION,
                            svm_input, num_elements*sizeof(int), 0, NULL,
                            NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clEnqueueSVMMap");

for(int i=0 ; i<num_elements ; i++)
{
    ((int*)svm_input)[i] = i;
}


for(int i=0 ; i<num_elements ; i++)
{
    std::cout << i << ", " << ((int*)svm_input)[i] << std::endl;
}

cl_status = clEnqueueSVMUnmap(queue, svm_input, 0, NULL, NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clEnqueueSVMUnmap");

cl_status = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(
    kernel, device, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t),
    &kernel_wrkgrp_size, NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo");

cl_status = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(
    kernel, device, CL_KERNEL_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(cl_ulong),
    &compile_wrkgrp_size, NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo");

cl_status = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(
    kernel, device, CL_KERNEL_COMPILE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE,
    sizeof(size_t)*3, &compile_wrkgrp_size, NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo");

size_t local_threads = 1;//kernel_wrkgrp_size;
size_t globl_threads = num_elements;

cl_status = clSetKernelArgSVMPointer(kernel, 0, (void*)(svm_input));
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clSetKernelArgSVMPointer");

cl_event ndr_event;
cl_status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
                                   &globl_threads, NULL,
                                   0, NULL, &ndr_event);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel");

cl_status = clFlush(queue);
CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(cl_status, "clFlush");
```

**On the kernel side:** the kernel is really simple.

```
__kernel void test_svm_kernel(__global void* input)
{
    __global int* intInput = (__global int*)(input);

    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    printf("intInput[%d] = %d\n", idx, intInput[idx]);
}
```

The output that I get in the host is:

```
Host: input[0] =  0
Host: input[1] =  1
Host: input[2] =  2
Host: input[3] =  3
Host: input[4] =  4
Host: input[5] =  5
Host: input[6] =  6
Host: input[7] =  7
Host: input[8] =  8
Host: input[9] =  9
```

which is the natural expected output.

On the kernel, I get strange output (and it changes sometimes):

```
input[0] = 0
input[1] = 2
input[3] = 1
input[5] = 5
input[1] = 7
input[8] = 1
input[0] = 0
input[0] = 0
input[0] = 0
input[0] = 0
```

I don't expect printf's on the device to be in order. However, at least to print array in a correct manner.

Any ideas how do I get such strange output?

Comment: Why do you pass to the kernel a void pointer and then you cast it? Also, you should be sure int and int in the host and device match. Because int can be 16/32/64 depending on the system. While a cl_int (what you should have used) is always 32bits.

Comment: Check if you get the correct output when using OpenCL 1.x. Also make sure you use the latest drivers - I experienced similar strange issue which was later fixed with drivers update.

Comment: Generally speaking, using printf to check something is risky, since it is fully debug and experimental (it also breaks the OpenCL execution model[fully parallel out of sync]). Checking the output is a better idea. For example, maybe the compiler optimized out all the kernel since you are not writing anywhere the input data.

Comment: Thank you guys for you comments. It turns out printf is not reliable and when I changed the input array and mapped it back to the host, the contents were perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, using printf to check something is risky, since it is fully debug and experimental (it also breaks the OpenCL execution model[fully parallel out of sync]). Checking the output is a better idea. For example, maybe the compiler optimized out all the kernel since you are not writing anywhere the input data. – DarkZeros

It turns out printf is not reliable and when I changed the input array and mapped it back to the host, the contents were perfectly correct. – Kareem Ergawy